# Problems in calculation , when user tries to fill record

Tags: process-builder

I have 5 fields,

- List Price
- Standard Discount %
- Standard Discount Amount
- Additional Discount %
- Additional Discount Amount..

When Standard Discount % is filled , and   Standard Discount Amount  is empty , it calculates Standard Discount Amount based on List price.

When Standard Discount Amount is filled , and   Standard Discount %  is empty , it calculates Standard Discount % based on List price,

I have used isblank functionality for this and its working fine.

However the problem arises, when I edit the record, because once the process builder is fired it automatically fills in both the fields , so even if I change the value on end , it doesnt perform the calculation as expected.

Now for the fields Additional Discount % and Additional Discount Amount..

Additional Discount % is calculated on the Amount that we get after ( List Price - Standard Discount Amount)

On filling the value for the first time , everything goes smooth. However, When user tries to edit the record. the calculation does not get performed.

How do I overcome this limitation?

Comment: It may be easier to conceptualize by using the dropdown filter checking for nulls instead of a formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ISBLANK` as criteria for running the rule actions editing the field from one value to another will not trigger the action. You can use `ISCHANGED` if this is the desired behavior. Without changing your criteria you can likely work around this by editing the field to a blank value, saving, and then editing again with your new value.

Comment: The current criteria before calculation is

AND(NOT(ISBLANK([OrderItem].Standard_Discount__c ))
,ISBLANK([OrderItem].Discount_Amount__c)
)

Can you suggest , how do I change it to get the desired output

Comment: Or do you mean, I should write a seperate workflow rule , which does that..